# I put in distinct but not fixing issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have an audit table and I want to show distinct on the id_key or maybe RX. this will reduce the duplicates. Some duplicates I cannot control bec we went live last month and there was some testing done. but if you look at the data: distinct and desired output are rx, seqno, and when reason is not blank

```
 ID_KEY   RX        SEQNO   STAT    REASON
 62261    5002616   7430    4   
 77848    5002616   12905   4       4
 91652    5002616   12905   4       4
 91652    5002616   12905   4       4
```

Ideally I would want to show distinct RX in this case. this may solve the issue entirely. The rows are in audit table means that the user accepted or declined. So they usually would not be in twice. once you accept or decline we don't display again in main user queue.

```
SELECT  
  a.ID_KEY,
  a.STAT, 
  a.TIER, 
  f.FACILITY_ID,  
  f.FACILITY_NAME Name, 
  a.RX, 
  a.PATIENTNAME, 
  a.MEDICATION , 
  (a.COST) as Cost, 
  (a.COST) as Interchanges,  
  s.Savings Savings
FROM[MBM].[T_CHARGES_AUDIT] a
```

Comment: what is the desired output exactly ?

Comment: I don't see the word DISTINCT in your select.  In any case, that keyword would return only DISTINCT for the entire set of columns you pull down.  So in the example you have there, you pulled 4 rows, 3 of which are unique.

Comment: desired output are rx, seqno, and when reason is not blank

Comment: Are we missing a join to table f?

Comment: there is a join but didn't think it was relevant

Comment: Perhaps there's no row where all columns combined are unique. Try using `DISTINCT` again but remove ID_KEY in the `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

This will show resutls with distinct a.RX.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  
  a.ID_KEY,
  a.STAT, 
  a.TIER, 
  f.FACILITY_ID,          --<-- Dont know how you got this Alias F here
  f.FACILITY_NAME Name,   --<-- Same here
  a.RX, 
  a.PATIENTNAME, 
  a.MEDICATION , 
  a.COST as Cost, 
  a.COST as Interchanges,  
  s.Savings Savings,         --<-- Again Alias S 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.RX ORDER BY a.RX) AS RN
FROM[MBM].[T_CHARGES_AUDIT] a 
)Sub
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: this is giving err:Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_GetDataDetail, Line 72
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.

Comment: Post all of your query, The error you are getting it has nothing to do with my proposed solution. Post your whole query and then maybe I can help you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you don't want distinct, you want one record per `RX/SeqNo`, which is not the same thing. It looks like your key is `ID_KEY`, so, assuming that is a normal, ascending key, the below SQL will give you the first record per RX/SeqNo. If you want the most recent entry instead, just change the `min` to `max`

```
SELECT  
  a.ID_KEY,
  a.STAT, 
  a.TIER, 
  f.FACILITY_ID,  
  f.FACILITY_NAME Name, 
  a.RX, 
  a.PATIENTNAME, 
  a.MEDICATION , 
  (a.COST) as Cost, 
  (a.COST) as Interchanges,  
  s.Savings Savings
FROM [MBM].[T_CHARGES_AUDIT] a
INNER JOIN (SELECT RX, SeqNo, min(ID_KEY)
            FROM [MBM].[T_CHARGES_AUDIT] a
            WHERE reason IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY RX, SeqNo) mins on a.ID_KEY = mins.ID_KEY
```

Note, this assumes that your `Reason` column, which is not specified in your select, is in the same table

EDIT:

To get the LATEST version of the combination, change `min` to `max` like this:

```
SELECT  
  a.ID_KEY,
  a.STAT, 
  a.TIER, 
  f.FACILITY_ID,  
  f.FACILITY_NAME Name, 
  a.RX, 
  a.PATIENTNAME, 
  a.MEDICATION , 
  (a.COST) as Cost, 
  (a.COST) as Interchanges,  
  s.Savings Savings
FROM [MBM].[T_CHARGES_AUDIT] a
INNER JOIN (SELECT RX, SeqNo, max(ID_KEY)
            FROM [MBM].[T_CHARGES_AUDIT] a
            WHERE reason IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY RX, SeqNo) maxs on a.ID_KEY = maxs.ID_KEY
```

Comment: i tried max but it has an error at s.savings line, msg 156 INNER JOIN (SELECT RX, SeqNo, max(ID_KEY)
            FROM [MBM].[T_CHARGES_AUDIT] a
            WHERE reason IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY RX, SeqNo) max on a.ID_KEY = max.ID_KEY

Comment: Without seeing the error message I can't say why, but I would guess that its because you used the `max` keywork to name the subselect. Note, I called mine `mins` NOT `min`..

Answer (score 0):

Try removing a column in your `SELECT` (**ID_KEY** or **RX**) and then use `DISTINCT` again.